# MKPlacemark: return US state abbreviation in AdministrativeArea

Tags: objective-c, cllocation, mkplacemark

I'm using the `MKPlacemark` class to populate a label with location specifics. When calling the `AdministrativeArea` property, the entire name of the US state is returned (e.g. West Virginia). Is there a way to return ONLY the initials (e.g. WV)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple's docs for that property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPlacemark/administrativeArea) suggest that there's no real definition for what it can contain. Your best bet is probably to create a function to map from the full state name to the 2 letter code, and pass the result of the property through it before display. I would default to the original string if you don't get a match.

```
-(NSString *)codeFromState:(NSString *)state {
  NSArray *map = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama",@"AL", @"Alaska",@"AK", ... @"Wyoming", @"WY", nil];
  for (int i = 0; i <[map count]; i+=2) {
    if ([state compare:[map objectAtIndex:i]] == NSOrderedSame) {
      return [map objectAtIndex:i+1];
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid all that, but I guess I have to. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if this can be sanely handled for provinces as well? (Accents may or may not be passed back.) I seem to recall reading that there was a way to do a comparison that lifted all of those differences away.

Comment: You might also check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518381/iphone-mkreversegeocoder-adminstrativearea-getting-state-abbreviation for a reference to a pre-built plist file containing the mapping and sample code to extract it.